# How can I debug native code called with p/invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, clion, rider

I am using **Rider** and **CLion** from jetbrains (I love their tools). I have an app written in C# that interops with a library written in C (OpenSSL).

I know in Visual Studio, I could tick the "debug native code" box and be done with it (so long as I had the PDB) but I am having one heck of a time getting rider and clion to play nicely together.

This is how I go about getting both debuggers attached:

1. Start the app from within rider and let it hit a breakpoint *before* the code I want to debug
2. Load the OpenSSL sources in CLion
3. Run `ps -ef | grep TLS` to find the managed process ID
4. Attach CLion to that process

After step 4, CLion forces me to step through some assembler, even though I hadn't set a breakpoint yet, and crashes the managed process.

So I am wondering, how can I go about debugging managed and native code in the same app using Rider and CLion?

Comment: Normally a process can only have one debugger attached. Pick one.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ahh, I see... Thats a little tricky because without being able to stop the managed code at a certain point, I'll never be able to attach the c debugger in time...

Comment: You can modify the code to enable that usually. Or have your C debugger start the host process but suspended.